# Mapnik Install: CentOS

Tags: python, centos, mapnik

**The problem:**

I've installed mapnik 3.0.1 successfully by running the typical source code install:

```
./configure
make && make install
ldconfig -v
```

However....

When I import mapnik into python I get the following:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 24 2015, 00:41:19) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mapnik
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mapnik
>>>
```

I've tried everything recommended on Mapnik's Troubleshooting page by *linking library paths*, editing `ld.so.conf`, etc...

I've been trying to figure this out all day, which isn't very productive. I've tried building other versions of mapnik, and the same thing happens. How do I get this imported???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a linking or linker error. That's a python module problem. Did you build and install the python module? To what path?

Comment: I believe the python modules are included in the source install of mapnik. That's what is confusing.

Comment: Where did `./configure` say it was going to install things? Where did `make install` say it did install things (probably buried in lots of other output)? If you run `updatedb; locate mapnik` does it find a python module? (Probably need to be root for the `updatedb` call.) Actually, what user did you run the configure/make/make install triple as?

Comment: According to online documentation it should be installed through installing the source package, unfortunately, the configure and make scripts are way to long to follow. I ran the install as root, as I'm just on a testing VM. I'm recompiling from source now, but once it's done I'll follow your instructions and give it a go and post an update, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you need the python bindings, which is a separate thing. As you mentioned they are actually included with mapnik 3.0 but you still haven't registered them (python doesn't know where they are). This is the easiest way I've found below:

**Install mapnik**:

```
brew install mapnik
```

Verify mapnik is installed (should be 3.0 now)

```
mapnik-config -v
```

**Install mapnik python bindings** (see here https://github.com/mapnik/python-mapnik):

```
git clone git@github.com:mapnik/python-mapnik.git
cd python-mapnik
python setup.py install
```